# Manually focus camera in EMGU CV

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, emgucv

I am using EMGU CV library in my application. How i can manually set camera focus to object? 
Now i'm using Capture class for grab images.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution by using [DirectShow](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/index.html). By IAMCameraControl interface i can control exposure and focusing of camera. Code sample:

```
 DsDevice[] devs = DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice); // getting video devices
 IFilterGraph2 graphBuilder = new FilterGraph() as IFilterGraph2; 
 IBaseFilter capFilter = null;
 if (graphBuilder != null)
 graphBuilder.AddSourceFilterForMoniker(devs[0].Mon, null, devs[0].Name, 
    out capFilter); //getting capture filter for converting it into IAMCameraControl
 IAMCameraControl _camera = capFilter as IAMCameraControl;
 _camera.Set(CameraControlProperty.Focus, 250, CameraControlFlags.Manual); //Setting focus to macro (in my camera, range between 0 - 250)
```

Comment: Given that this uses DirectShow.NET, does this mean it should, in theory, apply equally to Logitech and Microsoft webcams (in particular, the Microsoft LifeCam Studio)? We already have a Logitech C920 and we are facing the exact same problem. Hopefully your solution works even with .NET 4.5.2 on Windows 8.1 64-bit.

Comment: Someone has put this into a small C# prject on https://github.com/anotherlab/FocusUF

Answer (score 1):

EmguCV is essentially OpenCV for C#, it's just an image processing library. The Camera class is only useful for capturing images, not controlling camera parameters (you can see this clearly in [Emgu's documentation](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/18b6eba7-f18b-fa87-8bf2-2acff68988cb.htm)). In practice, there are many different kinds of camera, with varying controlling methods. Actually from your question I cannot infer which kind of camera are you working with: webcam, CCTV or photography DSLR?

The common approach you can take: use EmguCV to detect whether the camera is in or out of focus using [contrast detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autofocus#Contrast_detection) and control the camera accordingly. With webcams, they usually have autofocus built in, with other types of cameras, consult their documentation.

Comment: I'm using webcam Logitech C920 PRO. And i can control some parameters of camera  like exposure or saturation by Capture.SetCaptureProperty method. Camera  has autofocus, but i need a frame where object not in focus.